# Using django-oauth-toolkit with Django 2.x

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework, django-2.0

I've built a web application using django 2.0 and django-rest-framework. In my web app, I've been using django-rest-framework's `SessionAuthentication`.

I'm in the early stages of building out a supporting mobile app and based on my findings so far, there's a lot of value in doing the extra work to implement some sort of OAuth authentication:

- [django swift login system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36705533/django-swift-login-system)
- https://yeti.co/blog/oauth2-with-django-rest-framework/

I was hoping to use [django-oath-toolkit](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for this, but I noticed in the docs that there's no django 2.x support. I want to avoid refactoring my app using django 1.x, so two questions:

1. Has anyone used django-oath-toolkit successfully for django 2.x? (It appears that at least [some people have tried it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471093/where-to-put-django-oauth-toolkit-middleware-in-django-2).) Am I exposing my app to security risks if I go this route?
2. Are there any alternatives to django-oath-toolkit? Or am I wrong in my conclusion that a secure mobile application needs to use OAuth for authentication? (That conclusion was primarily drawn via this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578726/appropriate-choice-of-authentication-class-for-python-rest-api-used-by-web-app/27582256#27582256).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs might be out of date. If you look at official repo release notes, you can see it supports django 2.x starting from 1.2.0

Ref:
https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#120-2018-06-03